# Running time measurements of Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, time-complexity, dijkstra

I wrote an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm based on the pseudocode for it on Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm )  that used a priority queue with a min-heap. The graph was represented with an adjacency matrix (just like the pseudo code). And when I was gonna test it to see the running time, I thought I needed some large graphs to test on, so I randomly generated a few graphs of some size n (although the method I used to generate the graphs was probably quite bad).

Now, the complexity for this implementation is according to Wikipedia: O((|V|+|E|) log |V|).

When I ran the algorithm on V = 1000, e.g. a graph with 1000 nodes (I dont know how many edges though), on average it took about 800 ms. When I doubled the size of the graph with V = 2000, it took around 1700 ms, and when I doubled that (V = 4000), it took about twice as much.

So my question is (I know that my computer plays some part in the time measurements as well), shouldn't the running times be faster? Are these measurements reasonable?

Comment: You are using about 1ms for each vertex. That sounds like quite slow for a modern computer. Scaling sound about correct for size changes. But to measure performance you really should know the edge counts and that are all vertices actually connected.

Answer (score 2):

These measurements are reasonable; however, the runtime complexity is both worst-case and asymptotic. In fact, it would be most useful to evaluate the running times on instances where the worst-case is actually reached to experimentally estimate the runtime complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But wouldn't you say right now that, every time we double the input, the running time increases linearly, or slightly more?

Comment: As the running time apparently is `O(|V|+|E| log|V|)`, which means that the running time grows a little bit more than linearly. However note that it might be quite difficult (if not impossible) to actually find the respective worst-case for each instance size, as other data structues (priority queue) are involved. Furthermore, you have some machine-dependent factos like a caching hierarchy which may cause to the actual runtime bahaviour to differ from the asymptotic bound.